# Magento2 Create Dynamic Route For Products

Tags: php, magento2

So, i can't find correct, or any solution to this, while it seems like an important topic, basically creating a dynamic route for products or anything, for example, on my main page i get product collection in a list displayed within table, and while clicking on each product, i want to go on it's own page(ndex/products/1 or 2) and i can't figure out how magento2 deals with this, i would love the help, only hint i found it's somehow related to custom route, or cms route don't really know how though

Comment: Please name at least the Magento version (1 or 2) and frontend (e.g. rwd or luma) you're using. As to your question please [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit it to meet the criteria.

Comment: magento 2.3 and just using fresh installation luma theme